# Eventos con botones en php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema con `php`. Tengo dos botones uno de asistió y otro de no asistió con los cuales quiero que, cuando lo oprima se guarde en la base de datos para así llevar un control.

Si oprimo asistió, se guarde un **+1** en la bd y no haga nada mas. Si oprimo no asistió, se guarde en la base de datos y me redirija a un formulario de memorando.

```
<?php
  require_once '../conecion.php';
  if($conectarBD->connect_error ){    
    die("conexion fallida".$connetionBD->conect_error);
  }

  $cadena = "<table class='table table-striped table-light'><tr 
  align='center' class='bg-primary'><th scope='co'l>Numero De 
  Asistencia</th><th>Id Del Aprendiz</th><th>Nombre Del Aprendiz</th><th>Id 
  Del Turno</th><th>Fecha Del Turno</th><th>Hora De Llegada</th><th>Hora De 
  Salida<th>Asistencia</th></tr>";

  $sql = "select * from asistencia";
  if ($conectarBD->query($sql)->num_rows > 0){
    foreach ($conectarBD->query($sql) as $value){
      $cadena = $cadena."<tr align='center' class='font-weight-bold' scope='row'>
         <td>".$value['id_Asistencia']."</td>"
       ."<td>".$value['Id_Aprendiz']."</td>"
       ."<td>".$value['Nombre_Aprendiz']."</td>"
       ."<td>".$value['id_turno']."</td>"
       ."<td>".$value['fecha']."</td>"
       ."<td>".$value['hora_llegada']."</td>"
       ."<td>".$value['hora_salida']."</td>"    
       ."<td align='center' class='bg-secondary bg-lg bg-outline col-xs-3'> 
            <a class='btn btn-primary' href='#' onclick=agregar(".$value['Asistio'].")>Asistio</a> 
            <a class='btn btn-danger' href ='#'onclick=confirmar(".$value['NoAsistio'].")>No Asistio</a>
         </td>
      </tr>";
    }
    echo $cadena."</table>";
  } 
  $conectarBD->close();
?>
```

Comment: Y, ¿cómo funciona ahora? ¿Cuál es el código Javascript con el que escuchas los clicks del botón? Ya de entrada veo que mezclas dos ´onclick` ¿? No creo que eso funcione. Es más simple escuchar al botón olvidándote del valor, el cual conocerás vía Javascript y podrás ejecutar la acción adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta un espacio entre el href y el onclick

```
<a class='btn btn-danger' href ='#'onclick=confirmar(".$value['NoAsistio'].")>No Asistio</a>
```

debe ser

```
<a class='btn btn-danger' href ='#' onclick='confirmar(".$value['NoAsistio'].")'>No Asistio</a>
```

En la función confirmar puedes agregar una petición ajax para actualizar la base de datos y al recibir la respuesta de completado utilizar

```
window.location.href = "https://nuevodestino.com"
```

Para ajax por el amor de dios no uses jQuery si no lo tiene tu proyecto para otra cosa.
Yo recomiendo Axios o simplemente fetch si no te importa IE